# Javascript (Node js) big integer issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, biginteger, bigint, int64

Need to implement Diffie–Hellman algorithm with NodeJs using Big Integers

Compute A-side public key:
**A = Math.pow(g,a) % p**

where:

**p** - value must be 64bit integer,

**g** - value must be 32bit,

**a** - can be regular integer,

**A** - send to other partner , and receive B - other partners public key

Compute secret key S:
**S = Math.pow(B,a) % p**

**The main problem is implementation with NodeJs:
define 64bit integer values,
arithmetic actions with values,
send as buffer.** 
All libraries that I tried to use : 
'big-integer' ("big-integer": "^1.6.48"), 
'int64' ("node-int64": "^0.4.0")
don't solve the issue.

Comment: what have you implemented that didnt work?

Comment: Have you tried [bn.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bn.js)?

Comment: All libraries that I tried to use : 'big-integer' ("big-integer": "^1.6.48"), 'int64' ("node-int64": "^0.4.0") don't solve the issue:
*big-integer - can't retrieve from buffer
*int64 - have no arithmetic actions

Comment: `let g1t64 = new Int64(Buffer.from([0x04, 0x00, 0x4b, 0xdb, 0x57, 0xfe]));
let p1t64 = new Int64(Buffer.from([0x08, 0x00, 0x57, 0x0c, 0x17, 0xa3, 0x09, 0x2e, 0xcf, 0x88]));
let result = Math.pow(g1t64,3)%p1t64;
console.log(result);`         **// output: NaN**
    

`let result = bigInt(Buffer.from([0x04, 0x00, 0x4b, 0xdb, 0x57, 0xfe])).modPow(3, bigInt(Buffer.from([0x08, 0x00, 0x57, 0x0c, 0x17, 0xa3, 0x09, 0x2e, 0xcf, 0x88])));`
**output:
error: bigInt(...).modPow is not a function TypeError: bigInt(...).modPow is not a function**

Comment: from where you are getting `[0x04, 0x00, 0x4b, 0xdb, 0x57, 0xfe]`?

Comment: **this is my example , first two bytes this is length , other 4 bytes is a 32 length primary number** 
`let g1t32 = new Int64(Buffer.from([0x4b, 0xdb, 0x57, 0xfe])); 
        let p1t64 = new Int64(Buffer.from([0x57, 0x0c, 0x17, 0xa3, 0x09, 0x2e, 0xcf, 0x88])); 
        let results = Math.pow(g1t32,3)%p1t64; console.log(results);` **//result is also NaN** , I take buffer from wireshark it's hexadecimal representation of bytes sent by work examples , wrote with C#

Comment: Firstly, `math.pow()` is for [number types](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type), not for BigInts.  Secondly, with cryptographic-sized numbers you should never attempt to do modular exponentiation by first doing integer exponentiation followed by modular reduction. Always use a specialized function for this purpose. Thirdly, the geniuses defining the ECMAScript standard finally included a BigInt type but then moronically neglected to provide a modpow function. So write your own or use a third-party library that already has it.

Comment: @President James Moveon Polk I described formula for better understanding it's like pseudo-code.